# Custom databinding for collection of abstract classes in command object

Tags: grails

In a Grails 3.x project, I have a command object, `HabitatCommand`, that has a parameterized collection of animals:

```
class HabitatCommand {
    Set<Animal> animals = []
}
```

`Animal` is an abstract class and there are many concrete animal classes:

```
abstract class Animal {
    String name
    Integer height
    Integer weight
}

class Bird extends Animal {
    Integer wingspan
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    Integer lives
}
```

I'm sure databinding works fine if we're just selecting from existing animals and submitting their ids (as you would from a dropdown), but problems arise when trying to create new animal instances in the form. Take the following form data:

```
animals[0].name: 'animal1'
animals[0].height: 4
animals[0].weight: 75
animals[0].wingspan: 7
animals[1].name: 'animal2'
animals[1].height: 3
animals[1].weight: 45
animals[1].lives: 9
```

When databinding occurs, Grails loops over each `animals[i]` indexed form property and attempts to create a new instance of the parameterized type, in this case, `Animal`. This doesn't work since Animal is an abstract class, and I'd like to be able to customize that functionality to create the correct concrete Animal instance depending on the request params, e.g., if the `wingspan` property is present, we want to create an instance of `Bird`.

In other words, how can I hook into the databinding process to specify the concrete class to be used when creating each animal instance?

Is this possible? I've tried using a custom setter, `[].withDefault {}`, `@BindUsing`, and a custom `ValueConverter` but I don't believe any of those apply to this scenario and none of those solutions are ever even invoked.